# Get @ConfigurationProperties bean autowired in Junit

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit4

enter code hereI have a class annotated with @ConfigurationProperties in spring boot, how can I get this bean  autowired in  Junit tests

```
@ConfigurationProperties
 public class ConfigClass{
   public String property;
}
```

--Now under Test--

```
@RunWith(MockitoJunitRuner.class)
 class MyTests{

 @Autowired
 private ConfigClass configClass;

 @Test
 public myTest1(){
   String prop = configClass.getProperty();
   //Some assert
 }
```

-- configClass is coming out as null when I run this test --

Answer (score 0, accepted):

testing springboot with jUnit you can use @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) or @SpringbootTest which loads the entire context

if you want to test your config specifically use @TestConfiguration annotation. There are two ways of using the annotation Either on a static inner class in the same test class where we want to @Autowire the bean or create a separate test configuration class:

i will pick the first option inside static class

see example below ,

```
@ConfigurationProperties
 public class ConfigClass{
   public String property;
}
--Now under Test--

@RunWith(MockitoJunitRuner.class)
 class MyTests{


 @Autowired
 private ConfigClass configClass;

**// here use the @TestConfiguration annotation not @Test**

 @TestConfiguration
 public myTest1(){
   String prop = configClass.getProperty();
   //Some assert
 }
```

//Ok this works, now there is another class like below which is part of the test, and the configClass is not getting autowired there, any ideas

NB: i suggest to use the second option which is having  **separate test configuration class** to autowire all configurations across the classs like below

```
@TestConfiguration
public YourTestConfigurationClass ()
{
// plus all the other code which worked 

    @Component
    public class OtherClass{
 
      @Autowired
      private ConfigClass configClass;
   }
}
```

Comment: I am able to get Component and Respository beans in Junits but not Configurationproperties

Comment: @KiranChannayanamath can you please show ur code ?

Comment: I have edited the post, please find the code . @Ahmed Hosny

Comment: i ve updated my answer please check if it works for u

Comment: Yes that works, but there is another caveat I mentioned in your code, can you please check, sorry that was not mentioned in my original post  @AhmedHosny.

Comment: @KiranChannayanamath yes and i ve improved my answer please check & accept it as an answer

Comment: I tried that, OtherClass is a component part of main package, still getting null for the  configClass, I can accept your answer since I did not post the complete question.

Comment: please add @EnableConfigurationProperties in your test class

Comment: Added but no luck

Comment: have you defined separate test class  with @TestConfiguration for your config class ?

Comment: Yes I did @Ahemd Hosny

Comment: there should be something wrong keep trying and accept this as answer so that the question will be closed

Comment: Yes, thanks for your effort Ahmed Hosny